# Quaternion values from BNO055 not available

Tags: sensors, adafruit, esp32, bno055

I am trying to obtain Quaternion values from a BNO055 connected to ESP32-PoE board by Olimex.

### Code

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_Sensor.h>
#include <Adafruit_BNO055.h>
#include <utility/imumaths.h>

Adafruit_BNO055 bno = Adafruit_BNO055(55);




void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Wire.begin(13, 16, 400000);
  Serial.begin(115200);

  if (!bno.begin()) {
    Serial.println("No BNO055 Detected!");
    while(1);
  }
  delay(100);
  bno.setMode(Adafruit_BNO055::OPERATION_MODE_NDOF_FMC_OFF);
  bno.setExtCrystalUse(true);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  imu::Quaternion quat = bno.getQuat();
  imu::Vector<3> euler = quat.toEuler();

  Serial.print("W: ");
  Serial.print(quat.w());
  Serial.print(F(" "));

  Serial.print("x: ");
  Serial.print(quat.x());
  Serial.print(F(" "));

  Serial.print("y: ");
  Serial.print(quat.y());
  Serial.print(F(" "));

  Serial.print("z: ");
  Serial.print(quat.z());
  Serial.print(F(" "));

  Serial.print("X: ");
  Serial.print((float)euler.x());
  Serial.print(F(" "));
  Serial.print("Y: ");
  Serial.print((float)euler.y());
  Serial.print(F(" "));
  Serial.print("Z: ");
  Serial.print(float(euler.z()));
  Serial.print(F(" "));
  Serial.println("");
  delay(200);
}
```

#### output

```
W: 0.00 x: 0.00 y: 0.00 z: 0.00 X: 0.00 Y: nan Z: 0.00 
W: 0.00 x: 0.00 y: 0.00 z: 0.00 X: 0.00 Y: nan Z: 0.00 
W: 0.00 x: 0.00 y: 0.00 z: 0.00 X: 0.00 Y: nan Z: 0.00 
W: 0.00 x: 0.00 y: 0.00 z: 0.00 X: 0.00 Y: nan Z: 0.00 
W: 0.00 x: 0.00 y: 0.00 z: 0.00 X: 0.00 Y: nan Z: 0.00 
W: 0.00 x: 0.00 y: 0.00 z: 0.00 X: 0.00 Y: nan Z: 0.00 
W: 0.00 x: 0.00 y: 0.00 z: 0.00 X: 0.00 Y: nan Z: 0.00 
W: 0.00 x: 0.00 y: 0.00 z: 0.00 X: 0.00 Y: nan Z: 0.00 
W: 0.00 x: 0.00 y: 0.00 z: 0.00 X: 0.00 Y: nan Z: 0.00 
W: 0.00 x: 0.00 y: 0.00 z: 0.00 X: 0.00 Y: nan Z: 0.00
```

The sensor seems to be working since I tried a simple script and the values are avaiable.

Is there some specific setting missing during `setup()` in order to obtain Quaternions.

#### Purpose

For Absolute orientation, the Quaternion values need to be converted to Euler .

Comment: why setExtCrystalUse? has the module an external crystal?

Comment: I think it is for I2C clock. It is set to true in most applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently in the `setup()` it is preferable to have a `delay(1000)` as opposed to `delay(100)`.

#### Code

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_Sensor.h>
#include <Adafruit_BNO055.h>
#include <utility/imumaths.h>
#include <math.h>

#define DEG (180/M_PI)

Adafruit_BNO055 bno = Adafruit_BNO055(55);




void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Wire.begin(13, 16, 400000);
  Serial.begin(115200);

  if (!bno.begin()) {
    Serial.println("No BNO055 Detected!");
    while(1);
  }
  delay(1000);
  bno.setMode(Adafruit_BNO055::OPERATION_MODE_NDOF_FMC_OFF);
  bno.setExtCrystalUse(true);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  imu::Quaternion quat = bno.getQuat();
  imu::Vector<3> euler = quat.toEuler();

//  Serial.print("W: ");
//  Serial.print(quat.w());
//  Serial.print(F(" "));
//  
//  Serial.print("x: ");
//  Serial.print(quat.x());
//  Serial.print(F(" "));
//  
//  Serial.print("y: ");
//  Serial.print(quat.y());
//  Serial.print(F(" "));
//  
//  Serial.print("z: ");
//  Serial.print(quat.z());
//  Serial.print(F(" "));

  Serial.print("Yaw: ");
  Serial.print(euler[0] * DEG);
  Serial.print(F(" "));
  Serial.print("Pitch: ");
  Serial.print(euler[1] * DEG);
  Serial.print(F(" "));
  Serial.print("Roll: ");
  Serial.print(euler[2] * DEG);
  Serial.print(F(" "));
  Serial.println("");
  delay(200);
}
```